# No eth0 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

I think is not a duplicate. I quoted [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650953/intel-e1000e-ethernet-not-working) question as something I tried but did not solve my problem. Logs are also different.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my new computer. It has a Asus H81M-P motherboard (Intel I218-V Gigabit LAN). It does not detect my wired internet connection. **No eth0 exists,when I run `ifconfig -a` just `lo` appears**.

I read another questions of people with similar problems ([this](https://superuser.com/questions/1104537/how-to-repair-the-checksum-of-the-non-volatile-memory-nvm-of-intel-ethernet-co/1106641#1106641), [and this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650953/intel-e1000e-ethernet-not-working)) and at first it looked pretty simple. Install the e1000e Intel driver from source:

> sudo make install
>
> sudo modprobe -r e1000e
>
> sudo modprobe e1000e
>
> sudo update-initramfs -u
>
> reboot

But it did not work. After the failure I read [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191981) that it could be a problem of BIOS configuration related with `wake on Lan` property. I **disabled** the following options on my bios

- Secure boot (Changed from Windows to other OS to execute modprobe)
- Intel PXE OPROM
- PCI-Express Native Power Management
- Power-On by PCI-E
- PCI-E Active-State Power Management

And..... nothing! I have not a single clue about what is happening. ¿Can you help me?

EDIT: I add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1] (rev 05)
DeviceName: OnBoard LAN
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [1043:85c4]
Kernel modules e1000e

00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05)
Subsytem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI [1043:8354]
```

Edit 2: I add the output of `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100`

```
[1.710121] e1000e: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[1.710236] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[1.710754] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.3.5.3-NAPI
[1.710754] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2016 Intel Corporation.
[1.710900] e1000e: 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throthling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[2.493875] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2
```

Edit 3: Driver uninstalled, BIOS deafult values restored and Secure Boot disabled (as explained [here](https://www.all4os.com/windows/disable-asus-motherboards-uefi-secure-boot.html), it was trickier than i thought at first). Output of `dmesg | grep -e e1000 -e 19.0` added:

```
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.131920] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.132720] pci 0000:00:19.0: [8086:15a1] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.132731] pci 0000:00:19.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7d1ffff]
[    0.132737] pci 0000:00:19.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xf7d3d000-0xf7d3dfff]
[    0.132743] pci 0000:00:19.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xf080-0xf09f]
[    0.132790] pci 0000:00:19.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.132815] pci 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.158719] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed19000-0xfed19fff] has been reserved
[    1.519209] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
```

Edit 4: Ok. I'll try to give extra information. I bought two computers. Two exactly equal computers, same components. The first one is the one I am having trouble. The second one arrived today, and after all the problems I am having with the first I decided to disbale Secure Boot before installing ubuntu in the second computer.

Everything went smooth and wired connection was detected during installation. 0 problems. After this I was like 'what the flip?'... I tried the same with the first one. I restored BIOS to default values, disabled secure boot and reinstalled ubuntu. The problem persists. BUT `dmesg | grep -e e1000 -e 19.0` output changed:

```
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.124758] pci 0000:00:19.0: [8086:15a1] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.124769] pci 0000:00:19.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7d1ffff]
[    0.124775] pci 0000:00:19.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0xf7d3d000-0xf7d3dfff]
[    0.124781] pci 0000:00:19.0: reg 0x18: [io  0xf080-0xf09f]
[    0.124828] pci 0000:00:19.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.124852] pci 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.150756] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed19000-0xfed19fff] has been reserved
[    0.619102] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
```

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux PC1 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**After the success with the second computer, ¿could it be a physical/hardware  problem in pc1?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done, I added the output

Comment: I saw it, but I don't have any ideas. The adapter is supported, but the module is not loaded for some reason. Maybe because you installed an out-of-tree module. Try to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 already did it. Bios just allows two options (Secure boot for Windows and other OS) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Posted! And thanks! :), I think I saw some of your posts in Ubuntu Forums while looking for solutions.

Comment: It looks like Secure Boot is on. And also I suggest to remove that out-of tree module. You can do it by running `make uninstall` from a directory with its source. There is no need to install it.

Comment: "Probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -2" suggests that the driver tried to load and bailed out. I suggest that you remove the compiled driver as @Pilot6 suggests, reset the BIOS to defaults, reboot and show us again: `dmesg | grep -e e100 -e 19.0`

Comment: @Fantoni0 What is the kernel version? Please post the `uname -a` output. It looks the module is not there or doesn't support the card, but it should.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel e1000e Ethernet not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650953/intel-e1000e-ethernet-not-working)

Comment: @KrzysztofStasiak Though my opinion is biased, I think is not a duplicate.  I quoted that question as something I tried but did not solve my problem

Comment: Maybe its stupid, but can you swap od disk in computers? And check if working one os os working on second computer? Is the same hw/ BIOS revision on both ?

Comment: `module verification failed` suggest that module is not loaded, IT could be secureboot enabled, maybe try `mokutil`