# ethernet not working but is connected

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

The short story:

I just installed Ubuntu 20.4.2 on a tower that was previously running on Ubuntu 18.x. The network was working fine before the install, but I can't see any network now. I can see the ethernet port with `sudo lshw -c network` in the terminal, but can't ping anything.

my limitations:

- this computer has no wireless and
- I have no access to the router (at work)
- I'm relatively new to Linux (although I have a lot of experience with network issues in other OSes (Mac, DOS, Windoze from 1987 to present)

More details:

- The ping failures are `ping: connect: Network is unreachable` when I use an IP address, and `ping: connect: Temporary failure in name resolution` when I use a domain.
- The same network is being accessed by the computer I'm typing this on (ob) right down to the same switch. I have tried swapping cables and ports on the switch even though both of those seemed like long shots.
- The same network also works on a laptop I have running Ubuntu 20.4.2 as well.
- I saw a problem very similar to this one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267212/ethernet-connection-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04), but those solutions didn't help at all.
- Neither has any of the research I've been able to find.

Oh, and one more thing: the installer had to access the internet, didn't it? Maybe not.

TIA, community. I'm glad you're here.

Answer (score 0):

I am the same Tor Kingdon who posted it... hadn't realized I already had an account here. Oops. In any event, the problem seemed to go away when I brought that (rather heavy) tower home and hook it up to our home internet. If it returns when I get back to the work network, I'll contact the building's network provider. Thank you to anyone who has read this. (I'll also delete my duplicate account as soon as I can figure out how to log in to it. ;))