# e1000e-3.8.4 Installation Error

Tags: drivers, ethernet, intel

Im following this tutorial: [Intel e1000e Ethernet not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650953/intel-e1000e-ethernet-not-working)
I keep getting this eror tho... Could anybody help?

I have been trying to do this for a long time, but have had no success.. Help would be **very** helpful.

Pastebin URL : https://pastebin.com/3mzVwf5J

Thank You,
Gowixx

Comment: What is not working in the version already included in all recent Ubuntu versions? Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: It returns nothing! Just a blank command...

Comment: Let's dig deeper! `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Thanks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/E7LBKH1 here! It showed up.

Comment: Is e1000e loaded? `lsmod | grep e1000e` If not, load it and check the log again: `sudo modprobe e1000e && sudo dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oYd4x8H this is the response, i'm not sure...

Comment: Yes, the e1000e module is loaded. Now how about the message log? `sudo dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: It's blank! Nothing.

Comment: Stubborn problem! How about this long command in one line: `sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e && sudo dmesg | grep e100` There must be some clue somewhere!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ak6oivd

Comment: You have an interface and there are no errors! Does it try to connect? `sudo dmesg | grep eth0` What, exactly, is the problem that motivated you to try to install a diferent driver?

Comment: I plugged it in and it never worked... that's why i tried the drivers...